# Magento 2 CE Multiple Domains for Shops on Shared Server?

Tags: magento2

I'm looking for the simplest solution to having multiple-Magento shops on my web-server.

I've taken over support of 3 shops with different domain names and different shop software, i.e. OpenCart, Magento 1.9 and PHP.

The shops share a cross-section of products, but do not have the same menu configuration or full set of products. All products have the same price across the shops (at the moment) and same postage costs. The shops are multi-currency, i.e. GBP, EUR and USD.

Accees to Server configuration is minimal, HostMonster shared server. My aim is to get the 3 shops using Magento 2 CE with minimal amount of Magento software installations to save on disk space, but each shop must have its own domain name and individual products and customers.

Is the best solution 3 M2 CE installations or some other method?

Comment: If you want to use Magento you should use dedicated server (not shared) to assure performance. Or use Opencart. Opencart more flexible and faster.

Comment: Thank you K. B. We dont sell a great deal as it's a side arm to our brand sales.WIth OpenCart I don't seem to feel the flexibility you mention. Auto emails of payments and process etc seems difficult and hidden or have to pay for plugins. Unless you know different?

Comment: As have you described, OpenCart has all functionality on the default installation. The similar Plugins on OC marketplace are more cheaper than Magento. And most important thing, Magento very very very slow system. So you can try both of them and choose the best...